# How to handle solr similarity whole index database

Tags: solr, similarity

How can i found 20 documents that:

- to much similarity to each other as by content
- lower similarity to each other as by content

Answer (score 2):

Solr [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) feature can help you get the documents similar in content.
The similarity is based on the frequent terms occurring in the document.
The collection is queried for these terms to get the similar documents.

If you are looking to group documents, you would need a different tools for Clustering the documents. You can check Apache Mahout for Clustering.
This would cluster documents into groups using the TD/IDF approach.

Comment: Why didnt you recommend inbuilt Carrot2 clustering in Solr?

Comment: yup that can be an option as well. Although i have tried it. Would need to check